# Securing JBoss Web Artifacts

Tags: security, web, jboss

Question -- we are deploying a web application on Windows within JBoss  AS.  The application is accessed cleanly with a default page:

```
https://server:8443/app/
```

The user logs on and authenticates and then runs through the application.  However, we do have some web artifacts (images, JS files, etc) which are used to render the pages.  So a user could potentially bypass the authentication and go straight to these artifacts if they know the correct path:

```
https://server:8443/app/img/image.jpg
```

Is there a way to secure these artifacts?  Since it's bypassing our main servlet, we don't seem to have any access to block unauthenticated access, but really we don't want anybody to access these artifacts, only the web application as part of its processing.  We have gotten dinged in a penetration test for allowing this access.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is an easy question that I just don't know the answer to!

Answer (score 0):

### Declarative way

If you use declarative security, then simply put your security constraints to `web.xml`. To protect everything in the webapp you can use sth like:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protect all data</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Secured area</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Read more about it in [Anil's article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security) or in [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html)

### Programatic way

If you handle security programatically, then you can use a servlet filter, which will be mapped to all URLs (i.e. also images).

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```